# List of servers concatenated with domain name into one variable

Tags: ruby

I'm looking, if possible, to get a list of servers from a file and concatenate the server names along with a domain name. Is it possible to take that list and put it into one variable?

Here what I got and am trying to make into a variable or variables:

```
servers = YAML.load_file "/etc/servers/servers.yml"
clients = servers["client_servers"]
domain=`hostanme -d`

clients.each do |d|
  cservers = [ d, domain ].join('.')
end
```

Not sure how to do a `.each` and join the domain name in one line.

Comment: Can you provide sample input, and exactly what the resulting string would be?

Comment: `hostanme -d` will not work. You mean "hostname".

Comment: Where is an example of your input and the expected output? We really need to be able to see that.

Comment: hostname -d returns the domain name of the server I'm not, which is the same as the other servers. It's a linux box. I know it's not the best option. I also apologize for not putting the output. If you just do a "puts cservers" it will return the name of each server as server.domain.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying to add subdomains to a domain, correct?  If you have a hostname `example.com`, and a list of subdomains, you can join them like so:

```
hostname = 'example.com'
servers = ['www', 'staging', 'm']

full_hosts = servers.map{|server| [server, hostname].join(.)}
  #=> ['www.example.com', 'staging.example.com', 'm.example.com']
```

The `map` method takes a list, processes each item, and gives you a new list with the results. I've written more about it here:

http://rubycuts.com/enum-map